# How to make TreeView content is null

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to make TreeViewItem with empty ListBox in it's content looks like TreeViewItem without any content. For example a TreeViewItem "A" looks like as I wish. And when a ListBox in TreeViewItem "B" is empty I want to "B" looks like "A".

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem x:Name="A" Header="Header" />
        <TreeViewItem x:Name="B" Header="Header with empty list">
            <ListBox x:Name="localContent" ItemsSource="{Binding listContent}">
                <!--ListBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding listContent.Count}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="{Binding ElementName=localItem, Path=Background}">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Color R="0" G="0" B="0" /> 
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Style-->
            </ListBox>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Visibility` of your ListBox to `Collapsed` to make it not appear in your `TreeView`

Comment: No, a TreeViewItem as before have left cross expander

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are already doing something similar with count.

```
         <TreeViewItem x:Name="B" Header="Header with empty list">
            <ListBox x:Name="localContent" ItemsSource="{Binding listContent}">
                <ListBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding listContent.Count}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visiblity" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Style>
            </ListBox>
        </TreeViewItem>
```

Comment: No, a TreeViewItem as before have left cross expander

Answer (score 0):

achieved the desired behavior with the following triggers(add it for any controls):

```
<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource int2bool}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Expander Visibility="Hidden" />
                                <TextBlock Text="list is empty" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource int2bool}}" Value="True"  >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander Header="{Binding}">
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```